# In Blackberry OS 5.0 , Is there any UI Handler to update UI of the Screen

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an app with Blackberry OS 5.0. Is there any UI Handler(like  in android) which updates the  UI of the present screen. I am using thread's in my app,when a thread is running at the same time i need to update my UI of the screen.  Right now,after my thread is completed, i am popping the present screen and push the new screen again. Then only my UI is getting updated. Is there any alternative way to update UI when thread is running.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a much better way of doing it: Perform your updates on the UI thread. Example:

```
Application.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        editField.setText("My updated text");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Dountuner-I am displaying photo's in a grid view. If i click the image i need to put an image over it. I am able to do it, and updating the UI. But i am pushing the new screen again for every click on one image. Is there any other way .

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate the UI and update the UI you can also delete all Ui and reload it for particular condition.
like
getmainManger.deleteAll();

This method delete all UI and you can load new UI and update all UI.