# Is there any UI Handler for Blackberry OS 6.0

Tags: blackberry

I am developing a App in BB OS 6.0, Is there any UI handler which updates the UI changes that are changed in a Thread. Can any one give me some example link's

Comment: You already [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088189/in-blackberry-os-5-0-is-there-any-ui-handler-to-update-ui-of-the-screen) for OS 5.0, but didn't follow-up and accept an answer.  What are you trying to achieve, that you didn't get with the answers to that question?

Comment: Hey Nate, last time i have asked for BB OS 5.0. Now i want for BB OS 6.0

Comment: As far as I know, there's no difference in this issue in BB6 vs BB5.  And, you should still accept an answer when people take the time to give free advice.   Obviously, sometimes no correct answers are provided, but in this case, people have pointed you to the correct way to do this with both questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can do several things. The recommended approach would be wrapping your UI related code in a `Runnable`, then call either [`Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(Runnable)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [`Application.getApplication().invokeLater(Runnable)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29). The difference between these two is that `invokeAndWait` blocks until the event thread is available and the Runnable task is executed; and `invokeLater` just enqueues the Runnable and returns immediately.

There's also [an overloaded version of `invokeLater`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20boolean%29) to schedule a Runnable for repeated execution.

You could also wrap your UI related code in a synchronized block, and [try to lock on the event lock](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#getEventLock%28%29):

```
    synchronized(Application.getEventLock()){
        //GUI code here
    }
```

You should only lock the event thread for a short time, and this also applies to Runnables submited with the `invoke` methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Thread. 
Use

```
 UIApplication.getuiApplication.invokeLater(new Runnable()....
```

In its run method , change UI as per your need. It will reflect .